# Prepared statement Update

Tags: php

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE articles SET (menu_name, visible, content, photosp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ) WHERE id = ?");
$stmt-> bind_param("sissi",$menu_name,$visible,$content,$photosp1,$id);
$stmt->execute();

if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
    $stmt->close();  //Sucess
    $message = "The Page was successfully updated"; 
} else {
```

You Guys see anything wrong with this code? I probably just tired, but could use some help. I will see if I can get some more error reporting turned on. php.ini file right?
This is my error -- Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\

Comment: Is something not working...? If so: describe the problem.

Comment: Could you actually describe what isn't working? Did you intentionally forget the closing brace of your else statement when pasting?

Comment: your query statement has 5 parameters, but you're binding 6 of them... (menu_name, visible, content, photosp, id -> 5 --- "sissi", $menu_name, $visible, $content, $photosp, $id -> 6)

Comment: Yeah, don't you just need to remove the "sissi" bit?

Comment: The "sissi" is required for bind_param right? I am new to prepared statements

Comment: Robert Seddon below is right. Your Update statement is wrong. Your's just works for an insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sql syntax is wrong for an update:

```
UPDATE articles SET menu_name=?, visible=?, content=?, photosp=? WHERE id = ?
```

Should work.  Just set error reporting to E_ALL - it will really help with debugging.

Comment: Hey thanks man, I knew the "sissi" had to be in there. This post kind of took a hit on my rep though. I will turn on the Error reporting. Thanks again